# Python list from range

Tags: python-3.x, list, range

Could some one please make me understand the flow.

```
lst = [[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(3)]
for x in lst:
 for y in x:
   if y < 2:
     print('*', end='')
```

Comment: If you are using an IDE, like PyCharm, you can step into the code to understand how it is executed

Comment: I you use a debugger, you can understand the code. There are also ways to simplify this code...

Answer (score 1):

It does take some getting used to, but basically the following happens:

```
[[c for c in range(r)] for r in range(3)]
```

this creates 3 lists of length r within a list.
Then for every list (external loop) you look at every member of a given inner list (inner loop) and check whether it is less than 2. So the external loop runs three times and the inner - r times.